# How to check for invalid values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My brain might not be fully functional today, planets might be in a weird position, I might've crossed a black cat while passing under a ladder this morning. In any case I cannot wrap my mind around this.

```
products
- id
- group_id
- category_id
- brand_id
- name
- description
```

What I would like to do is generate a list of products that have no brand, no group and/or no category. So, if one of these three values is not filled I want to retrieve this value from my database.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE group_id IN ('', 0)
OR brand_id IN ('', 0)
OR category_id IN ('', 0)
```

Will the above query return results if more than one of the three values is empty?

So, what I'm actually asking: Does OR actually mean ANDOR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup your table correctly then you allow `null` values and then you can check for it

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE group_id is null
OR brand_id is null
OR category_id is null
```

`or` means only one of the conditions need to be met. If all conditions must be true, use `and`.

Comment: Lets say `group_id` and `brand_id` are null in a certain row. Will this query return this row even if `category_id` ìs not null?

Comment: Yes, it will. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Well, I could but it's a bit hard to check in the current db I'm working with. So I don't know if the correct records are returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do.

```
SELECT id, name, description FROM products WHERE group_id is null OR brand_id is null OR category_id is null;
```